# Inconsistent prediction results using LinearSVC from sklearn,

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm, liblinear

I am performing a simple classification using SKLearn's LinearSVC (LibLinear).

I cannot directly reproduce the predicted values and get the same accuracy as the "LinearSVC.predict" does.

What am I doing wrong? The following code is stand-alone and highlights my problem.

```
import scipy as sc
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC #liblinear
N=6000
m=500

D = sc.sparse.random(N,m, random_state = 1)
D.data *= 2
D.data -= 1
X = sc.sparse.csr_matrix(D)
y = (X.sum(axis = 1) > .0)*2-1.0 

x_train = X[:5000,:]
y_train = y[:5000,:]
x_test  = X[5000:,:]
y_test  = y[5000:,:]

clf = LinearSVC(C=.1, fit_intercept = False, loss= 'hinge')
clf.fit(x_train,np.array(y_train))

print "Direct prediction accuracy:\t",100-100*np.mean((np.sign(x_test*clf.coef_.T)!=y_test)+0.0) ,"%"
print "CLF prediction accuracy:\t",  100*clf.score(x_test,y_test),"%"
```

Output:

```
Direct prediction accuracy:     90.8 %
CLF prediction accuracy:        91.3 %
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference comes from how you treat zeros, when using `np.sign` you have zeros in the result which are not classified to any valid classes (1 or -1 since you have a binary classifier); The *Classifier.predict* on the other hand strictly outputs two classes; A tiny twist of your prediction method from `np.sign(x_test*clf.coef_.T)` to `(np.where(x_test * clf.coef_.T > 0, 1, -1)` will give exactly the same accuracy as the built in *predict* method:

```
​
print "Direct prediction accuracy:\t", 100-100*np.mean((np.where(x_test * clf.coef_.T > 0, 1, -1) != y_test)+0.0) ,"%"
print "CLF prediction accuracy:\t",  100*clf.score(x_test, y_test),"%"

# Direct prediction accuracy:   92.7 %
# CLF prediction accuracy:  92.7 %
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.